# Missing Ruby Development Libraries on OpenSuse

Tags: linux, opensuse, ruby

I might have jumped off the deep end when getting back into Linux and am stuck trying to install a new version of Ruby on OpenSuse with rbenv.

```
me@linux-tzyj:~> rbenv install 2.4.0
Downloading ruby-2.4.0.tar.bz2...
-> https://cache.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/2.4/ruby-2.4.0.tar.bz2
Installing ruby-2.4.0...

BUILD FAILED (openSUSE Tumbleweed 20180209 using ruby-build 20171226-3-g01e7b7b)

Inspect or clean up the working tree at /tmp/ruby-build.20180211014832.4210
Results logged to /tmp/ruby-build.20180211014832.4210.log

Last 10 log lines:
The Ruby openssl extension was not compiled.
The Ruby readline extension was not compiled.
The Ruby zlib extension was not compiled.
ERROR: Ruby install aborted due to missing extensions
Try running `apt-get install -y libssl-dev libreadline-dev zlib1g-dev` to fetch missing dependencies.
```

I tried finding any of those in apt-get and zypper with no luck.  Does OpenSuse handle these packages differently than Ubuntu does?  That is what I used to use years ago.

I tried running `zypper in -t pattern devel_basis` but that just removed the `zlib1g-dev` in the list of missing packages

Answer (score 1):

They are indeed slightly different. Try `zypper install libopenssl-devel readline-devel`.